# Eclips Java IDE EE not open

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I just download Eclipse java IDE EE developer I install file and when I open eclipse it shows a message "An Error has occurred " see the log file. what can I do?

Comment: Please provide the details of the entire error message.

Comment: Did you go to the log file to see if it actually gave a useful error message (it probably doesn't have a useful message but good to check in any case)? If it doesn't then uninstall, download a fresh copy of the installer, and try again. Your install may have been corrupted.

Comment: When i click to icon it shows me an error with message see a log file

Comment: So ... did you do what the error message said?

Answer (score 0):

1. Find your eclipse.ini configuration file `C://Users//YourName//eclipse//java-neon//eclipse`
2. Check and confirm the following lines are in the file.

   ```
   -vmargs
   -add-modules==java.se.ee
   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
   -Xms256m
   -Xmx1024m
   ```
3. Reboot Eclipse and it should launch for you now.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried deleting .snap file in .metadata/.plugins?

Also try to launch it with -clean option

```
./eclipse -clean
```